# CompanionDeviceManager associate method not calling callback methods

Tags: android

I am trying to use CompanionDeviceManager class to pair our BLE device with our Android (Version 10) phone without need of location permission. Here I am using below code:

```
 private void initialiseCompanionDeviceManager() {
    if (equalOrGreaterThanOreo()) {
        companionDeviceManager = getSystemService(CompanionDeviceManager.class);

        deviceFilter = new BluetoothLeDeviceFilter.Builder()/*.setNamePattern(Pattern.compile("fret zealot"))*/.build();
        pairingRequest = new AssociationRequest.Builder()
                .addDeviceFilter(deviceFilter)
               //.setSingleDevice(true)
                .build();
        associateDevice();
    }


}

private void associateDevice() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        companionDeviceManager.associate(pairingRequest, new CompanionDeviceManager.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onDeviceFound(IntentSender chooserLauncher) {
                try {
                    Log.e("BLEDevice", "Device found");
                    startIntentSenderForResult(chooserLauncher,
                            SELECT_DEVICE_REQUEST_CODE, null, 0, 0, 0);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("BLEDevice", "EXception");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(CharSequence error) {
                Log.e("BLEDevice", "Device error: "+error);
            }

        }, null);
    }
}
```

But it is not giving any callback in both methods. nothing happens. if anyone have idea about that, please bring me out of this.

Comment: I know this is bit old but did you manage to solve this issue?